# Python- obtain maximum value in an interval

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, argmax

I have a .CSV file (a list) that contains 43142 rows and 2 columns.

When plotting the list's values x vs y:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    filename=np.genfromtxt(list.CSV,delimiter=',')
    plt.plot(filename[:,0],filename[:,1])
```

I get a graph which has multiple maxima values and looks like this:
[x vs y values of list.CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XDpq.png)

What i want to do is, given an aproximate interval in the x values in which the peaks are positioned, find the maximum values and the corresponding indices on the list.

*e.g* if there's a maximum **y** value in the interval **x=(2720,2730)** (refer to figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNJwZ.png)), i want to find the exact index in which the value is maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a range `xmin < x < xmax` then this should work (taking `x=filename[:,0]` and `y=filename[:,1]`) :

```
idx = np.where(y==np.max(y[(x>xmin)&(x<xmax)]))[0][0]
```

This will return a single index corresponding to the maximum y value in the given range.

Comment: Thank you Angus. Does this give me the index in which y is max? or do i need to use np.argmax?

Comment: This gives you the index at which y is max when xmin < x < xmax.

Comment: It did. Sorry for the delay! Thank you